# Angular or tangential term in gravitational potential energy change using polar coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, potential-energy

I was studying gravitational potential energy and tried to derive the potential energy change using polar coordinates.
$$\Delta U=-\int m \overrightarrow g (d \overrightarrow r)$$

Now, I thought that $d \overrightarrow r$ could be a vector which is not parallel or perpendicular to $\overrightarrow r$ but at any arbitrary angle. Next, I split the $d \overrightarrow r$ into a radial and an angular (more appropriately a tangential component) to the field.

Since $ \overrightarrow r= r_r \hat r +  r_{\theta} \hat \theta$.

It follows that $$d \overrightarrow r = d(r_r \hat r) + d( r_{\theta} \hat \theta) $$

$$ d \overrightarrow r=d(r_r) \hat r+r_r d(\hat r) + d( r_{\theta}) \hat \theta + r_{\theta} d(\hat\theta) {\tag 1}$$

Now, we also know from knowledge of polar coordinates that $d\hat r= \dot\theta \hat\theta dt$ and $d\hat\theta=-\dot\theta  \hat r dt $

Substituting these values in (1),
$$d \overrightarrow r = d(r_r) \hat r + r_r \dot\theta \hat\theta dt + d(r_{\theta})\hat\theta - r_{\theta}\dot\theta  \hat r dt $$

Now substituting all this in equation of $\Delta U$,
$$\Delta U=-\int m \overrightarrow g (d \overrightarrow r)$$
$$\implies-\int m \overrightarrow g[ d(r_r) \hat r + r_r \dot\theta \hat\theta dt + d(r_{\theta})\hat\theta - r_{\theta}\dot\theta  \hat r dt]$$
$$\implies-\int m \overrightarrow g \hat r.dr - \int m \overrightarrow g.\hat\theta r_r \dot\theta dt - \int m \overrightarrow g. \hat\theta dr_{\theta} + \int m \overrightarrow g. \hat r \dot\theta r_{\theta} dt$$

Since $\overrightarrow g \perp \hat\theta , \overrightarrow g.\hat\theta=0$ , $\overrightarrow g. \hat r=-g$ and $\dot\theta dt=d\theta$, therefore second and third terms become 0 . The next equation simply become
$$-\int mgdr - \int mgr_{\theta}d\theta$$

I know that change in gravitational potential energy depends only on the radial distance between them. But this final equation seem to give a change in radial as well as angular direction while keeping radius constant. How could angular displacement really affect gravitational potential like the final equation indicates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position vector in polar coordinates is $\vec r = r_r\hat r$ in your notation, or simply $\vec r = r\hat r$ without the redundant subscript. [There is no component along $\hat \theta$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698290/position-vector-vs-polar-coordinates). Consequently the second term in your $\Delta U$ result is zero.

Comment: So I never had to consider $d\theta$ to begin with !

Comment: @Proscionexium It still shows up in $d\vec r$, but ultimately does not matter because the force has no $\hat\theta$ component.

Comment: @Proscionexium And that's why we love central force problems. ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem

Comment: @Puk That should have been clear to me when I said $\overrightarrow g \perp \hat \theta$. Thanks.